# Why the call to the class constructor freezes the application?

Tags: java, constructor, freeze

I'm developing a Java game and it's been working fine so far. I have no error messages or even warnings. The debugger seems to think everything is working properly, because it's not highlighting any lines of code in blue like it normally does when there's an issue. So to find out where the problem is happening, I have added print statements just before I call the constructor, to the first line in the constructor, in the paintComponent method, and in the run method. The only one that is being printed is the one just before the call to the constructor, so somehow the constructor is being called, but the first line of the constructor is never read, and the game loop isn't even running. Normally I would include an SSCCE, but I don't have the slightest clue what the problem is. Before I just start removing parts of my code until something works, is there anything specific that could be a likely culprit? What could be stopping the code in between the call to the constructor and the constructor code itself?

Comment: Have you tried stopping with a debugger during execution and seeing where it is? Have you added logging within the ctor?

Comment: 1.) use a debugger -.- 2.) the code is missing,  so it'll be difficult to answer the question 3.) serialVersionUID is used for serialization to identify the class of the object that is de-/serialized

Comment: You either have a blocking method or a recursive call

Comment: That's the thing: it's like the debugger doesn't even realize there's an issue! It normally highlights a line in blue where it having trouble, but it seems to think it's working as intended... I can post the whole code if you like, but it's quite long. I can't trim it down because I don't know where the problem is...

Comment: Start by trimming down as much of the code which still generates the area, placing "place holder" code for things that don't appear to be part of the probelm

Comment: @lenenard You're talking about the console output. They mean use the debugger that allows you to execute your code line by line and see if you're looping somewhere or not

Comment: Maybe you are doing something in the wrong thread? Do you implement some part of your program in SwingUtilites.invokeLater() ? It can freeze all GUI.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, you were right about the recursive function. Add an answer so I can accept it (:

Comment: Since you've added your own answer and I can't add anything more to it, I think it's okay to accept your own answer in this case ;)

Comment: ok, well thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out that it was a recursive function. I had added this code as a field in my game class:

```
public class Game extends JPanel {
    ////THIS WAS THE PROBLEM
    public static Movement a = new Movement(5, 5);
    ////
    Game () {}

}
```

And this code in the Movement class:

```
public class Movement {
    int x, y;
    ////THIS TOO
    Movement b = new Movement(0, 0);
    ////
    Movement(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Because each Movement has a Movement, which in turn has a Movement, it never even got to the first line in the game constructor. Thanks everyone for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If a VM process appears to be looping, the first step is to try to get a thread dump. If a thread dump can be obtained, it will often be clear which thread is looping. If the looping thread can be identified, then the trace stack in the thread dump can provide direction on where (and maybe why) the thread is looping.

If the application console (standard input/output) is available, then press the Ctrl-\ key combination (on Solaris OS or Linux) or the Ctrl-Break key combination (on Windows) to cause the HotSpot VM to print a thread dump, including thread state. On Solaris OS and Linux the thread dump can also be obtained by sending a SIGQUIT to the process (command kill -QUIT ). In this case the thread dump is printed to the standard output of the target process. The output might be directed to a file, depending on how the process was started.

Information about [ThreadDump](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tooldescr-136044.html#gbmpn)

If you are using IBM JDK Add the below JVM arguments 
-Xdump:java:events:user
Use Kill -3 pid for unix system and Ctrl+break for windows system.

Check the Threaddump and the method you invoke and the state of the thread to get clear picture of the freeze.